# Python CGI Script (using XML & mindom) does not print FOR loop counter

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Trying to print the results of a Yahoo search using an API, the For loop counter will not print its incremented value.  The XML is parsed and printed, but the counter prints '1' over and over.

The same code works fine for a Bing API.

```
for counter1 in range(50):
    try:
        for Result in YahooSearchResultsXML.getElementsByTagName('Result'):
            try:
                Yahoo_PageTitle = Result.getElementsByTagName('Title')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            except AttributeError:
                Yahoo_PageTitle = "Sorry, no page title provided..." 
            try:
                Yahoo_PageDesc = Result.getElementsByTagName('Summary')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            except AttributeError:
                Yahoo_PageDesc = "Sorry, no page description provided..."
            Yahoo_DisplayURL = Result.getElementsByTagName('DisplayUrl')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            Yahoo_URL = Result.getElementsByTagName('ClickUrl')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            ##  Print the output to ensure it's working.
            print counter1+1
            print "<br />"
            print "<h2>" + Yahoo_PageTitle + "</h2>"
            print Yahoo_PageDesc + "<br />"
            print Yahoo_DisplayURL + "<br />"
            print Yahoo_URL + "<br />"
            print "<p> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- </p>"
    except IndexError:
        print "Exiting@IndexError handler"
        break
    Yahoo_Score = counter1 + 1
```

Suggestions appreciated, have been looking at this code way too long now.

Comment: Why do you think the value of the counter should ever change?

Comment: You first two lines contain an IndentationError.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I fixed the indentation. It's pending peer review.

Comment: The indentation is correct in the original code, it must have happened during the paste.

Comment: I would really appreciate a sample XML document on which to run the code, to analyze what's happening. Or a URL from which I could download the XML.

Answer (score 0):

As it's written above, the printing is in the `for Result in..` loop. If you have multipe results, you'll get multiple lines with the same content.

<del>Also, the `try` shouldn't be indented?</del> (this was fixed)

Edit: from the info we gathered, you need to increment that counter in the inner loop. The way you have written it (`for counter1 in range(50)`) will increment it in outer loop.

Try this (pay attention to identation changes):

```
    counter1 = 0
    try:
        for Result in YahooSearchResultsXML.getElementsByTagName('Result'):
            try:
                Yahoo_PageTitle = Result.getElementsByTagName('Title')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            except AttributeError:
                Yahoo_PageTitle = "Sorry, no page title provided..." 
            try:
                Yahoo_PageDesc = Result.getElementsByTagName('Summary')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            except AttributeError:
                Yahoo_PageDesc = "Sorry, no page description provided..."
            Yahoo_DisplayURL = Result.getElementsByTagName('DisplayUrl')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            Yahoo_URL = Result.getElementsByTagName('ClickUrl')[counter1].firstChild.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
            ##  Print the output to ensure it's working.
            print counter1+1
            counter1 += 1
            print "<br />"
            print "<h2>" + Yahoo_PageTitle + "</h2>"
            print Yahoo_PageDesc + "<br />"
            print Yahoo_DisplayURL + "<br />"
            print Yahoo_URL + "<br />"
            print "<p> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- </p>"
    except IndexError:
        print "Exiting@IndexError handler"
        break
    Yahoo_Score = counter1 + 1
```

Comment: Dedenting the print statements causes the loop to iterate only once, printing one search result.  Then it breaks out of the loop due to the IndexError handler.

Comment: Add `print` to each `except` block, update the code and give an output, please

Comment: The outer loop is what needs to increment.  The inner loop is only to ensure that the script parses the tags within the 'Result' tags, and not other occurrences of those tags outside the 'Result' tags.

Comment: You are printing a value inside the inner loop and expect the output to be as if the printing was from the outer loop. If you don't understand this I give up.

Comment: The counter is just a variable, I should be able to print it from wherever I want.  Even if I try to print it from directly after the 'for counter in range(50):' statement, or directly after the first 'try:' statement, it will only print once.  It shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have more than 1 `Title` / `Summary` / `DisplayUrl` / `ClickUrl` in each `Result`? When the value of counter reaches 1, if there is no second `Title`/etc element somewhere in the XML, you'll jump to the `IndexError` handler and break out of the loop.

Comment: Each Result tag contains a Title/Summary/DisplayURL/ClickURL set of tags.

Comment: @user725236: your AttributeError exception handlers look suspicious, though : if no page title is provided, I'd excpect getElementsByTagName('Title') to return an empty list, and therefore you'll get an IndexError not an AttributeError. You should add a print statement in the IndexError handler to check that you are not exiting there unexpectedly.

Comment: @ gurney alex: As I said, it works fine for the big API, if there is no page title it prints "Sorry, no page title provided...".  I will try inserting the print statement as you suggest.

Tried that, exits due to IndexError as expected, after iterating through the XML completely.

Comment: @user725236: do we agree that you expect the code to display the first Title/etc of each Result in the document, then the second Title/etc. of each Result ?

Comment: The code should display the page title, followed by summary, display URl and actual URL of each search result.

Comment: @user725236 my question is about the order of the output. Since you have the counter loop outside the Result loop, you will be getting the order I mention in my previous comment. Is this what you want. Also please poste a short XML example and the expected output.

Comment: @gurneyalex let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1568/discussion-between-user725236-and-gurney-alex)